# winRT deleting an item from a gridview

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm developing a windows 8 store app and I'm having problems binding my items to a gridview.

```
ObservableCollection<<Customer>Customer> items = 
    new ObservableCollection<<Customer>Customer>();       

this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = items;
```

The question is : How can I delete an item or multiple items from the gridview and also delete it from the observable items?

Answer (score 1):

If your items class implement **ObservableCollection** when You delete item from collection, it will be also deleted from GridView.

Just use [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413.aspx) or [RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132414.aspx)